# Creating Rows Of A Character From Columns Data

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the data:

```
Name
------
Stack
Overflow
```

So there are two rows first row contains stack and second row contains overflow.

```
Output
------
S
t
a
c
k
o
v
e
.....
```

This is an example. The source can contain multiple rows. The output requires each row should be break down into number of character and each character should come in a new row

I tried writing SQL using Connect by but I am not getting appropriate results.

Comment: Try searching for split string, you'll find many good answers. Also, post your code to get help about it

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
with test(id, text) as (
    select 1, 'stack' from dual union all
    select 2, 'overflow' from dual
)
select character
from (
        select distinct id, substr(text, level, 1) as character, level
        from test
        connect by level <= length(text)
        order by id, level
     )
```

Comment: Great!  I write it on my personal diary :)